# back or cancel on search widget doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity

I did a search widget, which works fine. But when I pressed the back button, onCancel and onDismiss are never call.

In the PCRListActivity.java :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
    searchManager.setOnCancelListener(new SearchManager.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID_PRODUCTS, null, PCRListActivity.this);
        }
    });
    searchManager.setOnDismissListener(new SearchManager.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID_PRODUCTS, null, PCRListActivity.this);
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also meet this problem, and I have no choice but give up "oncloselistener". Instead, you can get your menuItem, then setOnActionExpandListener. Then override unimplents methods.
I guess that close and dissmiss methods just work for Progress Dialogs.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
//do what you want to when close the sesarchview
//remember to return true;

return true;
}
```